# retrieve results using union all with oracle

Tags: oracle

I have 3 tables with exact same structure

table1 contains today's data, table2 contains data of this week, table3 contains the rest of the data from the past, and rows are ordered by id

I want to retrieve last 500 rows from these tables depending on some 'where' conditions.

And for performance issues if table1 got 500rows that satisfy those conditions there is no need to look up on the other tables. same thing if we find 500 on table1 and table2 : there is no need to look up on the BIG table table3.

My goal is to not touch the big table table3 (and table2) as best as I can

My question is, if I do UnionAll, and if tables1 already contains the 500 rows that I need, is Oracle going to search on the table3 and table2 and waste some time on it (rows are ordered btw)? Or by doing UnionAll Oracle concats all the tables and then check what satisfies the conditions and then takes the first 500 rows, or there is a another option?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I tested this a little, and the results surprised me.

```
select 'test' from all_objects
union all 
select 'TEST' from all_objects
fetch first 500 rows only;
```

In this case, all 500 results show `test`. It's only pulling from the first query. This does seem to suggest that your idea would work. (NB: I'm using 12c syntax here, with the `fetch first X rows only`, but it should be the same with rownum.)

However, if you have an ORDER clause at the same level as the UNION ALL, it defeats the purpose, since Oracle will *have* to collect the full dataset in order to sort it - it can't just fetch the first 500 rows.

```
select 'test' from all_objects
union all 
select 'TEST' from all_objects
order by 1 asc
fetch first 500 rows only;
```

All results are `TEST`, and the query is slow. So yeah, don't do this. If you need to do ordering for display purposes, I'd nest it either inside or outside this UNION query.

Outside:

```
select * from
  (select 'test' from all_objects
  union all 
  select 'TEST' from all_objects
  fetch first 500 rows only)
order by 1 asc;
```

Inside:

```
select * from (select 'test' from all_objects order by 1 asc)
union all 
select * from (select 'TEST' from all_objects order by 1 asc)
fetch first 500 rows only;
```

Depending on what kind of sorting you want.

Comment: I am sorry i did not understand very well, you are selecting from only one table which is 'all_objects' ?

Comment: oh i see dont bother my question

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry that wasn't clear - it's a built-in view, I'm just using it as an example table with a lot of rows. :)

Comment: okay , but it takes time to order all the tables ? and also if you have table with lot of columns in that case order cost too much ?

Comment: Yes, ordering a large amount of data is always slow. Having an index on the column(s) you're ordering by can help.